# rotate image opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to rotate the output of Hue-histogram which is (5*1) into another image which should have (1*5) dimension.

I am using the following code but i am getting segmentation fault:

```
    MatND hist_input;
    calcHist( &hsv_input, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_input, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_input, hist_input, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    MatND rotated_histogram;
    rotated_histogram.create( 0,  hist_input.rows, CV_32FC1);

    for (int i=0; i<hist_input.rows; i++)
    {
        rotated_histogram.at<float>(0,i) = hist_input.at<float>(i,0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easier to use the `cv::MantND::t()` function. It is returning the transpose, so it is turning it for you.

I would add an observation too: the `at` is very slow, so if you are not doing this for test it is ok, but I suggest you to use `ptr` for applications